# Хук для OpenCart при создании ордера

Tags: php, opencart, события, hook

Использую OpenCart 2.1.0.1 
В этом движке есть events, при создании ордера я к нему подключаюсь, но ничего не происходит, почему?

```
public function install() 
{
    $this->load->model('extension/event');
    $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('create_order', 'post.order.add', 'shipping/mymodule/update_order');
}
public function update_order($order_id){
     // Load order data
    $this->load->model('checkout/order');
    $orderData = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);

   print_r($orderData);
   die;
}

public function uninstall() {
    $this->load->model('extension/event');
    $this->model_extension_event->deleteEvent('create_order');
}
```

Мне нужно выполнить определенное действие при создании ордера. Как это сделать? и почему не работает **"post.order.add"**?